# Any idea to detect the destination coordinate by specify time and distance to receive the location

Tags: android, geolocation

**EDIT:**

I want to detect the destination location contrast with my current location to send notification when I arrive at destination point.
But in the `requestLocationUpdates()` I set it to receive location with 15 mins, 1 km like this

```
MINIMUM_TIME_BETWEEN_UPDATES = 1000*60*15;
MINIMUM_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 1000;
    myManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                    MINIMUM_TIME_BETWEEN_UPDATES,
                    MINIMUM_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
```

During the travel, it may be pass destination point and miss to notify that.
Then I need the idea to handle this problem.
Any idea or suggestion to solve this problem ? All your help I really appreciate it.

Comment: your question is bit vague, could you please rephrase it. why method name requestLocationUpdate stores data in database...it's a request it should return something

Comment: @SkeetOverFlow Sorry and please see above. I already edited it. Hope you understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Any idea or suggestion to solve this problem

Use [`addProximityAlert()`](http://goo.gl/jy0j3), not `requestLocationUpdates()`, to find out when you are getting near a particular destination location.

Comment: Can I use both bec I also need to keep logs to route path later ?